# Метод решения СЛАУ LU-разложение (нахождение L и U)

Tags: матрицы, matlab

Реализация численных методов в MATLAB. Ищу матрицы L и U, результат похож на правду, но совсем не то, что дает встроенная функция (дело даже не в переставленных строчках). Подскажете, что не так делаю?

Исходная матрица

```
    A = [ 8.3 -8.9 -5.3;
      9.5  5.2 -6.8;
      7.1 -9.7  3.2 ];

b = [ 4.1;
      3.9;
      8.3 ];

[L,U] = Part12(A);

disp(L);
disp(U);
```

и сама функция Part12

```
function [ L, U ] = Part12( A )

%первый шаг
L = zeros(3);
U = zeros(3);
L = diag(ones(1,3));

k=1;
n=3;
r=1;

while 1

    for j=r:n
        U(r,j) = A(r,j)-sum( L(r,k:(r-1))*U(k:(r-1),j) );
    end

    if r==n
        break;
    end

    for i=(r+1:n)
       L(i,r) = (1/U(r,r))*( A(i,r) - sum(L(i,k:(r-1))*U(k:(r-1),r))); 
    end
    r=r+1;
end

end
```

Получаю (первая матрица - L, вторая - U):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

встроенная функция дает такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что не так делаю? 15ю и 23ю строку, там где сумма заменял отдельной переменной, которую суммировал циклом - все точно так же, так что вряд ли проблема в этом, скорее всего недопонял алгоритм. Кто подскажет?
Заранее спасибо!